# MPMoviePlayerController setFullScreen not working ios6

Tags: ios, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a very weird problem with the MPMovieplayercontroller in iOS 6.

I've debugged for hours, and can finally conclude that there is something wrong with setFullscreen:NO animated:NO in iOS6.

My project support iOS below 6.0 also, and there it works like it should. 
The following line of codes behave differently depending on iOS version.

```
NSLog(@"player fullscreen 1 = %u", self.player.isFullscreen);
[self.player setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
NSLog(@"player fullscreen 2 = %u", self.player.isFullscreen);
```

player fullscreen 1 = prints 1 in both iOS 6 & below, which it should because it is fullscreen.

player fullscreen 2 = prints 1 in iOS6 and 0 in other version. This is a problem because the logic in the class is depending on this, and it ends with a weird behaviour when i try to close the view.

Anyone have a solution to why setfullscreen doesnt work in iOS 6?

(on a sidenote i call [self.player setFullscreen:YES animated:NO] when im starting the player and this does so its starts in fullscreen, but cant get it back from fullscreen..)

And yes - i need it to start in fullscreen!

Also make sure that i have nothing in viewDidDisappear and viewWillDisappear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt find the perfect solution, but i made a selector with a delay with 0.0f, which means it will run in the next cycle.

I had to do this, because the code wasn't execude properly without !

Answer (score 0):

In iOS6 , when you tap on toggle button to go to full screen, the viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisAppear of self and parent controller gets called which was not the case prior to iOS6.Debug your code there, if it is creating any problem.

Comment: As mentioned, i also read about that problem. But the main problem is that setFullScreen doesnt change state.. Its fullscreen even if i set it to NO. Thats the main problem. 

And as far i can see, no one of my viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear is called..